# Why are they using .first here?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

In my class they used the following code:

```
pet = session.query(Pet).filter_by(name="Marshmallow").first()
```

What does the `.first()` do here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`.first()` returns the first object matched by the query, or `None` if there was no match. Without `.first()`, `session.query(Pet).filter_by(name="Marshmallow")` returns an instance of [`Query`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/query.html#the-query-object), not the object.

See the official SQLAlchemy document [`Query.first()`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.first).